# Is there a way to proactively end a prompt, i.e with a timer or event, from the WaterfallStepContext in the Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, azure, dialog, botframework

From what I see, in the nodejs framework, I notice you can't prompt a user within a dialogflow dialog and retrieve the that prompt within the same dialog function... I may be wrong about that.  Either way, you can return prompt and retrieve it in the next dialog flow.

Is there a way to cut off the awaiting prompt for user input and end or resume an activity of the dialog?

I would like to cut the prompt off at a certain point, ideally on a time basis.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible thru using a combination of sending a proactive message, filtering via  `onMessage()` and `onSendActivities`, and a dialog interruption.

First, in **index.js**, I setup an API for sending proactive messages.

```js
server.get('/api/interrupt', async (req, res) => {
  for (const conversationReference of Object.values(conversationReferences)) {
    await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
      var reply = { type: ActivityTypes.Message };

      const yesBtn = { type: ActionTypes.PostBack, title: 'Yes', value: 'Yes' };
      const noBtn = { type: ActionTypes.PostBack, title: 'No', value: 'No' };

      const card = CardFactory.heroCard(
        'Want to skip out and see Star Wars?',
        null,
        [ yesBtn, noBtn ]
      );

      reply.attachments = [ card ];

      await turnContext.sendActivity(reply);
      return { status: DialogTurnStatus.waiting };
    });
  }

  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.write('<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent.</h1></body></html>');
  res.end();
});
```

In **mainBot.js**:

- I create a state property for setting whether the timer should be active or not. I also create an empty `timer` object.
- I assign the timer state property to a variable (`activityTimer`) along with a default value (`null`).
- In `onMessage()`, I filter on `channelId` ("directline") and `role` ("user").
- I filter on whether the user selected the 'Yes' option from the proactive message. If so, the dialog(s) are cancelled, `timerState` is set to `false`, and the timer is cleared. This ensures the timer won't fire once the dialog is cancelled. New input from the user is required to start the dialog, again.
- Any other user input sets the `timerState` to `true` and clears the timer. This ensures multiple timers do not stack when new user input is received by clearing any current timers and flagging a new timer to start.
- Lastly, if `timerState` is set to `true`, then `setTimeout()` is called, assigned to the `timer` variable, with a timeout value of 5 seconds. At this point, an API call is made to the "interrupt" endpoint I created in `index.js`, which sends the proactive message, and `timerState` is set back to `false`.

```js
this.activityTimerAccessor = conversationState.createProperty('activityTimer');

let timer;
this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
  if (activity.channelId === 'directline') {
    if (activity.from.role === 'user') {
      let text = activity.text.toLowerCase();
      switch (text === 'yes') {
      case true:
        if (activity.channelData.postBack) {
          activityTimer.timerState = false;
        }
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
        break;
      default:
        activityTimer.timerState = true;
        if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
      }
    }

    if (activityTimer.timerState === true) {
      timer = await setTimeout(async () => {
        await fetch('http://localhost:3978/api/interrupt');
      }, 5000);
      activityTimer.timerState = false;
    }
  }

}
```

In **mainDialog.js**, I extend `cancelAndHelpDialog.js` which is where any interruptions are caught. If you are unfamiliar with interruptions, you can read about them in the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-handle-user-interrupt?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript) and reference a sample [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot).

```js
const { CancelAndHelpDialog } = require( './cancelAndHelpDialog' );
const MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG = 'MainWaterfallDialog';

class MainDialog extends CancelAndHelpDialog {
  constructor ( id, userState, conversationState ) {
    super( id, userState, conversationState );

    this.mainId = id;
    this.userState = userState;
    this.conversationState = conversationState;

    this.addDialog( new AdaptiveCardDialog( ADAPTIVE_CARD_WATERFALL_DIALOG ) )
      .addDialog( new WaterfallDialog( MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG, [
           this.simpleSend.bind(this)
      ] ) ) ;

    this.initialDialogId = MAIN_WATERFALL_DIALOG;
  }

  async simpleSend ( stepContext ) {
    await stepContext.context.sendActivity('Looks like you said or did something...')
    return await stepContext.next();
  }
}

module.exports.MainDialog = MainDialog;
```

In **cancelAndHelpDialog.js**, I create a new `ComponentDialog` which contains an "interrupt" method. In `interrupt()`, I filter for the user selecting the "Yes" button from the proactive message indicating the user's wish to cancel the dialog(s). If pressed, I notify the user and cancel all dialogs.

```js
class CancelAndHelpDialog extends ComponentDialog {

  [...]

  async interrupt(innerDc, next) {
    const activity = innerDc.context.activity;
    const text = innerDc.context.activity.text.toLowerCase();
    if (activity.type === 'message' && activity.channelId === 'directline') {
      if (text === 'yes' && activity.channelData.postBack === true) {
        await innerDc.context.sendActivity("Cancelling...Let's go see a movie!!");

        return await innerDc.cancelAllDialogs();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This should set you up going in the right direction. Obviously, alter to fit your needs. For instance, the proactive message doesn't have to take user input sending just a message that is picked up and triggers an interruption.

Hope of help!