# botframework v4 proactive messages not going through activityhandler event handlers

Tags: node.js, botframework

I Have a notification dialog to be invoked proactively...

e.g.

```
Bot: Hi, you have an event scheduled in next 15 mts... blah blah
Bot: would you want me to email the details?
User input: yes/no
Bot: Great!
```

This is a simple waterfall dialog... 
step1  inform and prompt confirm.
step2. process user input..

Now this dialog is initiated proactively .
step 1 works.
However the dialogContext / dialogStack is not getting saved and when user says yes it is going to main dailog and not this proactive dialog which should be on top of stack.

Basically, none of the activityHandler methods like onDialog event on the activityHandler are getting invoked for proactive dialog.

Question is how to have the messages from proactive Dialog go through activityHandler methods so that the dialogStack is persisted ?

I use nodejs.

**Updating with Code sample below**
// middleware

```
const { ActivityTypes } = require('botbuilder');



class MyMiddleware {

    async onTurn(context, next) {


        await context.onSendActivities(async (context, activities, nextSend) => {
            console.log(`messages: ${activities.map( a => a.text).join(',')}`)
            return await nextSend();
        });

        // By calling next() you ensure that the next Middleware is run.
        return await next();
    };


}

module.exports.MyMiddleware = MyMiddleware;
```

// main bot.

```
const { ActivityHandler, TurnContext } = require('botbuilder');

class ProactiveBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor(conversationReferences) {
        super();

        this.conversationReferences = conversationReferences;

        this.onConversationUpdate(async (context, next) => {
            this.addConversationReference(context.activity);

            await next();
        });

        this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
            const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;
            for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; cnt++) {
                if (membersAdded[cnt].id !== context.activity.recipient.id) {
                    const welcomeMessage = 'Welcome to the Proactive Bot sample.  Navigate to http://localhost:3978/api/notify to proactively message everyone who has previously messaged this bot.';
                    await context.sendActivity(welcomeMessage);
                }
            }

            await next();
        });

        this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
            this.addConversationReference(context.activity);

            await context.sendActivity(`You sent '${ context.activity.text }'`);
            await next();
        });

        this.onDialog(async (context, next) =>{
            console.log(`I am called`)
        })
    }

    addConversationReference(activity) {
        const conversationReference = TurnContext.getConversationReference(activity);
        this.conversationReferences[conversationReference.conversation.id] = conversationReference;
    }
}

module.exports.ProactiveBot = ProactiveBot;
```

// index

```
const bot = new ProactiveBot(conversationReferences);

server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        // Route to main dialog.
        await bot.run(context);
    });

});
server.get('/api/notify', async (req, res) => {
    for (const conversationReference of Object.values(conversationReferences)) {
        await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
            await turnContext.sendActivity('proactive hello');
        });
    }

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.write('<html><body><h1>Proactive messages have been sent.</h1></body></html>');
    res.end();
});
```

When I call notify api I expect the onDialog event to be called... and print "I am called". But that doest not get printed to console.

Comment: Tried doing conversationState.saveChanges(context, false) but that did not save the dialogState.. note: dialogState is a property of conversationState.

Comment: workaround : for every prompt step, immediately after the prompt step doing conversationState.saveChanges(context, true ) saves...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you do not have the following bit of code in your "mainBot.js" file. Adding it should solve your problem and not require you to save state after every step. I have a proactive dialog that presents the user with a "yes/no" option, as well. However, I do not have to save with every step in order to capture the user's response.

```js
this.onDialog(async (context, next) => {
  console.log('Dialog detected');

  // Save any state changes.
  await this.conversationState.saveChanges(context, false);
  await this.userState.saveChanges(context, false);

  await next();
});
```

That being said, I have a component dialog that is listening for the user's choice sending an appropriate response. The proactive dialog is not being captured but the response context is. Because the "mainDailog.js" extends the component dialog the context is added to the stack which is then processed via the `this.onDialog()` method in "mainBot.js". Thus, state is saved. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58964283/is-there-a-way-to-proactively-end-a-prompt-i-e-with-a-timer-or-event-from-the/59079076#59079076) SO response I posted recently that demo's this setup which includes the above code but is not displayed. In that case, the user also wanted a timer built into the process which you can ignore.

Hope of help!

Comment: I have. If I dont have even normal dialogs wont work.

Comment: @UdayaBhaskarReddy, are you able to add any relevant code into you original post? If you are saving state via onDialog() (which I guessed you were, but I like to double check stuff), then something somewhere is changing the state again before it is getting saved.

Comment: ok. For now I am doing the force state save before the prompt in proactive dialogs as a workaround. So, it is supposed to work and something in my code is preventing it, right? will dig and see. for now, could not figure out why. btw, mine is a waterfallDialog and not a component dialog

Comment: Are you able to update your post and include the code for your "mainBot.js" and "mainDialog.js" files (hide any keys/secrets)? Whether waterfall or component, state should still save properly via the `onDialog` method.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't fully appreciating the question you were asking. The proactive message is not getting picked up because it isn't being run thru the `adapter.processActivity()` method (used when activities are passed thru `/api/messages`). The `/api/notify` API uses `adapter.continueConversation()` to inject into the conversation bypassing the activity processor.

Comment: Look over [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58964283/is-there-a-way-to-proactively-end-a-prompt-i-e-with-a-timer-or-event-from-the/59079076#59079076) which demonstrates using a combination of a proactive message, interruptions, and activity handlers. Their use case is different from yours but certainly close enough for you to adjust to your needs providing a means for capturing _representative_ proactive message activity in the activity handlers.